# My for-loop doesn't give me all numbers

Tags: c++, for-loop, numbers

I have a very simple code, but still it doesn't work the way i want it. It should give me back all n which it goes trough, but I only get the last one: "10000001". What did i wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n=1000;
  int i=1;
  for(;i<3;n*=100,i++);
    {
    cout <<  ++n << "\n";
    int* temp = new int[n];
    delete [] temp;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for(;i<3;n*=100,i++);
```

You don't need the semicolon at the end. You are running an empty loop by doing this.

Comment: I'd say that answer is *very* misleadingly phrased: It's not "you don't need", it's rather "you *must not* put a semicolon after the `for` statement"!